# Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" - trying to add Bootstrap to a Spring project

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, bootstrap-5

I tried adding bootstrap to my spring project. I added the thymeleaf reference in the html tag and now i get this error. Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
\<!DOCTYPE html\>
\<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://thymeleaf.org"\>
\<head\>
\<meta charset="UTF-8"\>
\<title\>Welcome to my Application\</title\>

\</head\>
\<body\>
\<h1\>Welcome to my Application\</h1\>
\</body\>
\</html\>
```

This is the whole log

```
`SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory loaded from file:/C:/Users/Ariciu/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.instanceCheckFailed(Assert.java:713)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:632)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLoggerContext(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:369)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:238)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:220)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$starting$0(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:300)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
    at com.vladlaudat.java_crud_app.JavaCrudAppApplication.main(JavaCrudAppApplication.java:10)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 2 more`
```

Comment: can you put a reproducer into github ?

Comment: i have fixed it, just created and started over, i think there was a problem with the ide's dependencies. gotta love programming :D